# Creating web api to make calls to another web api

Tags: .net, facebook-graph-api, web, asp.net-web-api, code-reuse

What I would like to do is create a web api that makes calls to facebook api. It this possible or is there any other way?

The reason I want to this is because I would like to allow android/ios apps to make calls to my web api which calls the facebook api. My web api will contain different formulas and conditions.  This will allow me to reuse my codes with other devices and not make me write code for my different apps/devices.

Basically is create a central web api that gets data from facebook api.

Comment: just make an call to facebook api inside your api method

Comment: Of course it is possible. What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call an api from your api.

I would start by looking up System.Net.WebRequest.  With that you can construct your request to facebook and have all your logic in the middle.